# How to compare column in 2 list with linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

How to compare and take only products in list product where p.street==a.street
List products {p1, p2, p3}       list address {a1, a2, a3}

**Example:**

1. ListProduct= {P1, Paris} {P2, London} {P3 New York} {P4 Bagdad} {P5 Rome}
2. Liste Adresse= {A1, Paris} {A2, Rome}

3.ListeProductResult= {P1, Paris} {P5 Rome}

Both solutions work very well Thanks I want to add a second list for comparison
CategorieProduct={c1,c2}

It works but what is the best solution

```
 var result = from product in ListProduct 
         join address in ListAddresse on product.Street equals address.Street 
         join Categories in ListCategories on product.CategorieNom equals Categorie.CategorieNom  select product;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using those lists as follows: (assuming `Street` is the property that we are comparing)

```
var result = productsList
         .Where(product => addressList
                         .Any(address => address.Street == product.Street));
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way of doing this is to use a `join` - this will match the properties across the two different entities

```
var result = from product in ListProduct
             join address in ListAddresse on product.Street equals address.Street
             select product;
```

If this gives you multiple matches (e.g. if you had multiple matching addresses for a single product) then you could then additionally apply Distinct() to the output of this query.

For more examples of Linq in action, please see the excellent [101 linq examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx) on MSDN - including a section on joins - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647#crossjoin

Comment: Both solutions work very well Thanks I want to add a second list for comparison CategorieProduct={c1,c2}

Comment: Both solutions work very well Thanks I want to add a second list for comparison
CategorieProduct={c1,c2}

It works but what is the best solution

     var result = from product in ListProduct 
             join address in ListAddresse on product.Street equals address.Street 
             join Categories in ListCategories on product.CategorieNom equals Categorie.CategorieNom  select product;

Comment: I can't see you're entire new question - but it looks like you've got the right idea - just keep adding additional join's as required. Note that using "join" is efficient because it's mapped back to the SQL database as a JOIN - and database engines are very good at doing JOINs